# Пунктуация в предложении после слова "что"

Tags: запятые

В ответ на Ваше письмо сообщаем, что, для рассмотрения вопроса и выдачи положительного заключения по существу Вашего письма, необходимо дополнить предоставленную проектную документацию по следующим вопросам:

Нужно ли обрамлять запятыми "для рассмотрения вопроса и выдачи положительного заключения по существу Вашего письма" ??

Answer (score 2):

*В ответ на Ваше письмо сообщаем, что д**ля рассмотрения вопроса и выдачи положительного заключения по существу Вашего письма** необходимо дополнить предоставленную проектную документацию по следующим вопросам:*

В деловом стиле обстоятельственный оборот, выраженный падежной формой существительных,  не обособляется.

При обособлении оборот приобретет вставочный характер (будет выделен по смыслу и интонации), а этого в деловых бумагах обычно не требуется.

**Стилевая неточность**: повтор слов *ваше письмо, ваш вопрос.*

Как вариант:

*В ответ на Ваше письмо сообщаем, что для рассмотрения вопроса и выдачи  по нему положительного заключения необходимо дополнить предоставленную проектную документацию по следующим позициям:*